# A website is crashing-closing the android default browser

Tags: javascript, android, browser, joomla2.5

I have a very weird pb. A client website (in developpment) crash/closed the Android default browser (tested on 2 tablets and genymotion virtual android). If we disable js, the browser stop crzsking. It's the only browser whiçth pb. Any of coul create this ? The website is make with Joomla! 2.5 and some classic omponents (sobipro etc). these are using massively google api/map if it could help...

Comment: We have no way of telling what is causing the problem without some sort of error log or code sample.

Comment: I understand.. So this is the link of the current developpment : http://62.39.117.242 . It happens when we play with the top menu.